# Website changing content using bootstrap and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have found this example where there is one `form.html` page where it contains its design for the navigational bar using bootstrap. The other page is just a `content.html` page where it just contains the content and a jquery script. 
Example of the content page:

```
<body><h1>hello world!</h1></body>
<--jquery script calling another function from a .js file-->
```

When I access `form.html`and for example I will click the messages tab in the navigation bar It will display the `content.html` inside the `form.html`

My question is how can that be done. Its efficient that we don't have to copy and paste the design again. Was that a function of jquery? Are there any online tuturials for that? I can't find the solution.

Comment: you can `include` the form.html into any other html page without copy n pasting the same design again.

Comment: @Bhugy Yes,  but I would like to know how he did it without using `include`.

Comment: Can you provide the reference to the website or something you found this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer the following links,you may get an idea,

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_ajax

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_text_set

http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_html_replacewith

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("button").click(function(){
        $("p").text("Hello world!");
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<button>Set text content for all p elements</button>

<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

For link,I have added the code for dynamically changing content while loading gif according to the link processed.Till the link is processed,it will show the loading image with its respective content.
Below overlay function is used for loading gif image.

```
 <script>
var overlay = {

    click_on_overlay_hide : true,

    show_loading_image : true,

    loading_image : "images/loading.gif",

    $ : function(id) {
        return document.getElementById(id);
    },

    init : function() {
        var ol_div = document.createElement("div");

        ol_div.id = "overlay";
        ol_div.style.display = "none";
        ol_div.onclick = (this.click_on_overlay_hide) ? overlay.hide : null;

        if (this.show_loading_image) {
            var l_img = document.createElement("img");

            l_img.src = this.loading_image;
            l_img.style.position = "absolute";
            l_img.style.top = (((window.innerHeight) ? window.innerHeight
                    : document.body.clientHeight) / 2)
                    + "px";
            l_img.style.left = (((window.innerWidth) ? window.innerWidth
                    : document.body.clientWidth) / 2)
                    + "px";

            ol_div.appendChild(l_img);
        }

        document.body.appendChild(ol_div);
    },

    show : function() {
        if (this.$("overlay")) {
            this.$("overlay").style.display = "";
        }
    },

    hide : function() {
        if (overlay.$("overlay")) {
            overlay.$("overlay").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

}
        function First() {
                document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = "<center><h6>I am First</h6></center>";
                        }
        function Second() {
                document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = "";
                document.getElementById("di").innerHTML = "<center><h6>I am Second</h6></center>";
            }
      </script>

 <body onload=overlay.init();">      
               <div style="display: none;" id="overlay">
                        <h1>
                            <img class="centerImg" src="images/loading.gif">

    //Below tag content will change according to the link processed
                            <div id="di">Processing the url...</div>

                        </h1>
                    </div>


      //First link  
      //It will call the First() and changes the content of id="di" into  "I am First" ,displayed along with the gif image,till the href link is processed.
   <a href="services/dealjson/first" onclick="First(); overlay.show(); setTimeout('overlay.hide()', 20000)">FIRST</a>

      //Second link      
   <a href="services/dealjson/second" onclick="Second(); overlay.show(); setTimeout('overlay.hide()', 13000)">SECOND</a>
  </body>
```

Comment: how about if it just a link? not a button.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you are asking how the form/content pages are sharing the same design/navigation bar.  If so there are a few ways to do this.

- As you previously mentioned, copy and paste, but this is difficult to maintain.
- The navigation bar is part of the websites master page.  And form/content pages are ... well bodies of this master page.  This option though reloads the navigation bar, but does not need it to be recoded for every page it appears in.
- Ajax, as you had suspected.  The body of the webpage can dynamically be updated with javascript calls using ajax.  Here the navigation bar is not reloaded as the content changes.